# FreeBSD VMware and CAM status: SCSI Status Error

Tags: vmware-esxi, freebsd, storage-area-network, scsi

I'm running a FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE-p19 on a VPS (VMware).

My ISP is experience a rapid data growth, and these messages spontaneous started to show up in our logs a week ago.

```
Sep 25 09:00:50 srv03 kernel: (da0:mpt0:0:0:0): SCSI status: Busy
Sep 25 09:00:50 srv03 kernel: (da0:mpt0:0:0:0): Retrying command
Sep 25 09:00:50 srv03 kernel: (da0:mpt0:0:0:0): WRITE(10). CDB: 2a 00 03 f9 6c 22 00 00 40 00
Sep 25 09:00:50 srv03 kernel: (da0:mpt0:0:0:0): CAM status: SCSI Status Error
```

Sometimes the server is totally losing contact with the storage, and then panic and restarts. This often occur every even hour, presumably by a routine job (migration/backup).

Until my ISP have added more storage system, that will lower the load on the storage, I really want to try do something.

I have found this, but are unsure how to patch/use the information:
https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=278111

I also found this (`vfs.unmapped_buf_allowed=0`), but I'm unsure if this could be related?
https://www.freebsd.org/releases/10.1R/errata.html#open-issues

`camcontrol tags da0 -v`

```
(pass1:mpt0:0:0:0): dev_openings  127
(pass1:mpt0:0:0:0): dev_active    0
(pass1:mpt0:0:0:0): devq_openings 127
(pass1:mpt0:0:0:0): devq_queued   0
(pass1:mpt0:0:0:0): held          -1
(pass1:mpt0:0:0:0): mintags       2
(pass1:mpt0:0:0:0): maxtags       255
```

`gstat` info when errors occur:
[image]

Any thoughts, hints, ideas would be really really really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VMWare, thus mpt(4) is purely virtual, I would suggest changing it to something more simple, like ICH10.

Otherwise I suggest you play with `camcontrol tags`, either increasing or decreasing queue length.

If you'll chose to reprovision disks using another driver, notice that SAS -> SATA controller change may result in device naming change, probably `/dev/daX` will become `/dev/adaX`,  so unless you are using zfs or mounting your disks via disk labels, you'll have to edit `/etc/fstab`.

As about your `gstat` output - there's clearly something wrong with it, probably to the nature of the virtual environment support in FreeBSD. 600% load is nonsense. I suggest you report this into the FreeBSD Bugzilla.

P.S. The advice to change disk provisioning controller type still stands.
P.P.S. Or. Or I would try to lover the queue length of the mpt(4) to 128 or even 64.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @drookie, please let me get back with a `gstat` snapshot to start with. The man page says that novice users (like me), should stay away from `camcontrol` - sounds a bit scary.

Comment: Your'e right, but this time I advise you so. I tried this by myself on mpt(4) with LSI 1064 controller family, no devastating or even harmful consequencies encountered (though I didn't notice any improvements too, in my case). But you're right, it's your equipment. I updated my answer too, please notice changes.

Comment: Thanks again @drookie - I have found this, that seems to address and fix  this exact problem: https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=278111 A upgrade to 10.2-Release resolved the issues. Thanks for your input!